# How do I get the identifier from the user object?

Tags: openid, identifier, gigya

How do you retrieve the identifier from the user object? Normally, I would expect the identifier to be something like this:

`https:\\me.yahoo.com\bob#bob123`

Looking at [the user object](http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Objects/User_object), however, it doesn't seem like there's an equivalent. I have to use the providerUID to store my users instead. Yesterday Google provided me with two different providerUIDs for the same user.